# Bootstrap 4 Fixed Right Sidebar

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

Please can someone advise, im using webforms with a masterpage.  On my content page i am trying to have a static sidebar on the right hand side.  I have found some examples which is mostly working however ideally this sidebar will be the full size of the contents page.

It is currently displaying like so:

screenshot

[image]

And the page level is:

```
<style type="text/css">

    #sidebar {
        background-color: #eee;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
    }

</style>


<div class="row">

<div class="column col-xs-9" id="main">              

  <p>Details</p>
  <p>Details</p>

  </div>

        <div class="column col-xs-3" id="sidebar">

            <nav>
                <ul class="nav flex-column list-style-icons">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Identity"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i><b>Section 1:</b> info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 2: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 3: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 4: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 5: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 6: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 7: </b>info</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " href="#Body"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i><b>Section 8: </b>info</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Notes:</li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>

            </div>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just think about: height is 100% of what exactly? Anyway, you could use `height: 100vh;` (combined with calc if `needed`) which is a context agnostic setting - but it will have some [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) limitations